# php send html email with .csv attachment

Tags: php, csv, html-email, email-attachments

I am sending an email through php no problem.  I want to attach a .csv file along with the HTML email provided.  I can't seem to find how to do that.  Is there a certain Content-Type I also have to include in the `$headers` along with a `Content-Disposition` of **attachment**?

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'A Subject Line';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>List of New Price Changes</title>
</head>
<body>";

$message .="HTML table";
$message .="</body></html>";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send CSV file attached to the email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816421/send-csv-file-attached-to-the-email)

Comment: yes I saw that post but it does not explain what does what such as multipart messages which is I think what I am looking for

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 $fileatt_type = "text/csv";
$myfile = "myfile.csv";

        $file_size = filesize($myfile);
        $handle = fopen($myfile, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);

        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $message = "<html>
<head>
  <title>List of New Price Changes</title>
</head>
<body><table><tr><td>MAKE</td></tr></table></body></html>";

        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

        #$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        #$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: text/csv; name=\"".$myfile."\"\r\n"; // use diff. tyoes here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$myfile."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."--";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Try to modify the code for your situation.

Comment: Will it work for a simple boundary such as "Bound bound bound"?

Comment: Why do you put your own boundary? The code calculates you a nice one.

Comment: This is what I get in my email with NO attachement: `MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_xaa04eec9f70b8e7b42496fa47f70257dx"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--==Multipart_Boundary_xaa04eec9f70b8e7b42496fa47f70257dx
Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

--==Multipart_Boundary_xaa04eec9f70b8e7b42496fa47f70257dx
Content-Type: text/csv;
 name=""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

TUFLRSxNT0RFTA0KQU1BTkEsSERDMTgyDQo=


--==Multipart_Boundary_xaa04eec9f70b8e7b42496fa47f70257dx--`

Comment: That code is for a one attachment. To send email with no attachment, you need to change and remove some lines. It would still send the email but as you see the headers get a little complicated and unnecessary now. Try with a file :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11027/discussion-between-toddn-and-ata-s)

Comment: This was exactly what I've been searching for, thanks for the example!

Comment: I believe this answer is now outdated. I was able to find a solution to the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887610/error-with-php-mail-multiple-or-malformed-newlines-found-in-additional-header

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing HTTP headers with mail.... You probably want to send a [multipart messages](http://rand-mh.sourceforge.net/book/overall/mulmes.html), but instead of reimplementing it, I'd go for something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

**This code works for me. You can try this.**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');
if (!$con)
{
    die("error" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$filename = "adhaar_info";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM adhaar_info order by id desc limit 0,10");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$filename2='datas/'.$filename.'.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename2, "w");
$seperator = "";
$comma = "";
foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $name);$comma = ",";}
$seperator .= "\n";
$seperator;
fputs($fp, $seperator);
mysqli_data_seek($sql, 0);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $seperator = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $value);$comma = ",";}
    $seperator .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $seperator);
}

fclose($fp);

$my_file = $filename2;
$path = "datas/";
$from_name = "solomon";
$from_mail = "pss@gmail.com";
$mailto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$message = "Hi,\r\n do you got attachment?\r\n\r\Solomon";
$replyto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$file = $my_file;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "--";
mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)

?>
```