# Trying to send csv attachment AND body text in email

Tags: php

I have been able to write php script (with HTML) to $_REQUEST online form data entry and either 
(1) write to a CSV and email it as an attachment, or 
(2) include data in the body of any email.

But I cannot do both at the same time. I want the CSV for quick import into database, and I want email body to also include the details so the shipping dept has a pick list for packing. How do I get both features to work simultaneously without interfering with each other?

Thank you in advance.

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
        $to = "name@domain.com";
        $subject = "Order - " . $_Tech_Name;

        //Add the headers 
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                   "From: {$email_from}\n" .
                   "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                   " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

        // email body includes only fields not null
        $body = "";
        foreach ($_REQUEST as $Field=>$Value) { 
            if($Value != ''){
                $body .= "$Field: $Value\n\n";
            }
        }
        $email_body = "Here are the details: \n\n $body";

        // csv file name format
        $today = date("m.d.y"); 
        $csv_name = "order - " . $_Tech_Name . " " . $today . ".csv";
        $fp = fopen($csv_name,'a');
        fwrite($fp,$data);
        fclose($fp);

        $attachments[] = Array(
           'data' => $data,
           'name' => $csv_name,
           'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        );

       //Add sttachments
        foreach($attachments as $attachment){
           $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment['data']));
           $name = $attachment['name'];
           $type = $attachment['type'];

           $message .= 
                      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                      " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                      $data . "\n\n" ;
        }
```

**PHP SCRIPT - I have isolated the problem with the following additional script that is part of the script shown above, but I do not as yet understand why it is a problem. By commenting out either $message (attachment) or $email_body (body only) I am able to get one or the other to work. But if I leave both variables in there, then neither works **

```
        mail(
            $to, 
            $subject, 
            $message,     // for attachment only
        //  $email_body,  // for body only 
            $headers
            );
```

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816421/send-csv-file-attached-to-the-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By isolating the problem in my original post I was able to get it to work by writing two (2) "mail" commands as follows:

```
        // attachment 
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        // body
        mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

I am happy with this solution, but if someone can find a way to get the same email to include the body content and attach a CSV, that would be ideal.